# AC TO DC Converter IC

Tags: power-supply, power, switch-mode-power-supply, power-electronics, ac-dc

I am using a small circuit which needs 5V DC input and total current consumption of the circuit is 300mA. I have been using the small size ac to dc converter modules, but now i am searching for a small size IC which will do the AC To DC conversion.
I have been looking all over internet i have found LNK586xx IC but due to lack of Electronics knowledge i could not find the usage circuit for it and unable to understand the usage.

My question is , Is there are other IC which does the required thing.
I am looking for a guidance on this issue. My basic requirement is to make the power circuit most compact than what i am using right now. I am using HLK-2M05 Hilink module. 
Link to device which i am currently using . 
https://datasheet.lcsc.com/szlcsc/1912111437_HI-LINK-HLK-2M05_C209909.pdf

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. You need to write a better specification. (1) What is the AC voltage? (2) You have specified 300 mA out at 5 V. How much ripple can you tolerate on the 5 V output? (3) "*...  to make the power circuit most compact than what i am using right now.*" We don't know what you're using right now.

Comment: Make it more compact than what.... let’s see if I can find my crystal ball. Better still define what you mean and remember that shopping questions are off topic.

Comment: I think you are slightly out of your depth, AC to DC offline conversion can be dangerous and requires a decent amount of design even with the best IC chips.

Comment: @Transistor : hi . i am using HLK-2M05 HiLink module. 
How much ripple can you tolerate on the 5 V output <- i am unaware of these details in electronics due to lack of knowledge and no background of electronics.

Comment: @MadHatter Thats the guidance i am looking for.

Comment: @Andyaka  I totally understand that, i found stack as the last option only hence wrote the question here.

Comment: The device is more than just a chip internally. It will use a small isolation transformer too hence why it specifies a 3 kV isolation level between AC pins and DC output. Not easy to get much smaller in my opinion.

Comment: Why are you complicating things? Today's cell phone charger are really compact and can output 5V @ 2A why don't you just use a cellphone charger and get a USB adapter to connect to your load. And the IC you got is extremely tiny compared to the actual size of most common power supplies out there.

Comment: @javabee What is the AC voltage?

Comment: @Ariser-reinstateMonica 230 V AC

Comment: @javabee 230V AC and "lack of Electronics knowledge" usually don't match very good. You or so else might be dead or heavily injured in the end. Use a wall wart and be happy. Or pay an engineer for building what you need. Or study EE. There aren't any other options without an option on visiting jail for some time or paying another costly price.

Comment: @Ariser-reinstateMonica : Hi. I appreciate for giving good suggestions.
Pay an engineer for building what you need <- this would be nice advice, but currently i do not have time to study EE or going to jail for some time.
Precautions are taken at my end while working on 230V. 
Please guide me in the solution for the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the usage circuit of the LNK586, you find it on page 4 of the datasheet and I copied it here:

[image: Usage circuit]

The blue part is a rectifier (AC to DC), the orange part is the IC which forms the control part of a DC/DC convertor (green part)

Regarding your second question: You can find many ICs that make the same thing (control a DC/DC convertor), however, to design an offline (direct from AC mains) power supply is not trivial at all. To get a circuit that is significantly more compact that the module you’re currently using would be extremely challenging: most of the space in your current solution is most likely used by the passive components, to reduce them you would need to increase the switching frequency of the DC/DC convertor but that would increase the switching losses in the power transistors and magnetic components at the same time.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the Texas Instrument tool to design your AC/DC converter. 
WebBench TI : https://webench.ti.com/power-designer/switching-regulator

In the option of the design consideration, choose small footprint .